# Can one program with idle MPI ranks/cores utilize the idle underlying cores as OpenMP threads for the non-idle ranks?

Tags: mpi, openmp, hpc

I'm running into an edge case between pure MPI and hybrid MPI+OpenMP, and I'm not sure how to get MPI+OpenMP to do what I want, but also afraid I'm running into an XY problem.

Let's say I run a program with two parts, A and B, on a machine with 64 cores. These parts are never going to be executed in parallel. During the execution of part A, I can use all 64 cores as MPI ranks. During the execution of part B, I can use only 8 MPI ranks. If I map each core to one rank, then part A fully utilizes my machine, but part B leaves me with `64-8=56` idle cores. I would like to use these idle cores to speed up the execution of part B that is being run on the 8 MPI ranks.

The only way I know how to do this would be if part B was its own program. Then part B in of itself could be a hybrid MPI+OpenMP program, where there are 8 MPI ranks, and each rank maps to a set of 8 cores, of which OpenMP can be used to speed up the execution by running each core as an OpenMP thread. Is it possible to replicate part B being its own program, but actually it's just part B of one program that also runs part A as previously described?

If it matters, I'm programming everything in C++.

Comment: I guess that this mixed solution is easy to program. The difficulty is to make it run effectively. For that, you'll need to 1/ deactivate MPI polling (env variable depending on your MPI) 2/ bind the MPI processes to sets of 8 cores with 1 MPI process which will spawn OpenMP threads per set. And that should do the trick. NB, the non-polling aspect might decrease the performance of your pure-MPI part...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't see where is the problem: 1) in A you don't use OpenMP directives at all; 2) only the first 8 MPI processes execute B; 3) in B you use OpemMP directives. `omp_set_num_threads(8)` has to be called at the beginning of B.

Comment: The problem can occur if the MPI library or the resource manager binds each (of the 64) MPI tasks to its own core: part B will end up having its OpenMP threads time sharing. The solution was given in the first comment.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work @Gilles, if you're deactivating MPI polling and binding one MPI process to 8 cores, doesn't that explicitly mean that you will not run part A across all 64 cores of the machine?

Comment: you simply need to bind 8 MPI tasks to each set of 8 cores for it to work. For example, if you have 8 sockets with 8 cores each, bind each MPI task to a socket. The 64 MPI tasks will use th 64 available cores, but each socket (8 cores) will be shared by 8 MPI tasks. Not ideal strictly speaking, but the OS scheduler should handle it just fine.